# Does np.zeros define a global variable

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    x += 3
    return x

x_initial = np.zeros(3)
print(x_initial)
print(f(x_initial))
print(x_initial)
```

And it returns:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.]
[ 3.  3.  3.]
[ 3.  3.  3.]
```

It seems like 'x_initial' is a global variable. Why?

Comment: @DanielY: no, it is not defined outside of the function.  Here both the local variable `x` and `x_initial` refer to the same object. `x` is local to the function, but the object that it refers to is mutable, so changes made to the object via that reference change the object.

Comment: if you don't want your function to mutate the input, use `x = x + 3` instead of `x += 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x_initial` is a mutable object. Passing it to function `f()` and modifying it there will modify the object. It's the same as if you passed a list into a function and modified it:

```
def f(l):
    l.append('something extra')

l = []
f(l)
print(l)
f(l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['something extra']
['something extra', 'something extra']
```

Comment: But if I set x_initial = 0, it won't be modified by the function. What's the difference?

Comment: 0 is an integer, and integers are not mutable. If x were an integer, your function will modify the value of the object referenced by the local variable x, but assigning a new value to it does not modify the original, it just rebinds it. In the case of a `numpy` array, `x += 3` actually modifies the array (because numpy overrides the `+=` operator). In the list example that I show in my answer it is a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, I see. If I don't want to modify the original numpy array, how can I make it ?

Comment: @jiangniao: pass a copy of the array into the function, or make a copy in the function before operating on it: `f(x_initial.copy())` or inside `f()`: `x = x.copy()`.